# Reassigning a datasource at run-time

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

I did some searching and only found more unanswered questions. :)

Using D5pro.

I want to reassign the DataSource to a TDBGrid at run time. I have seven identical structured DataSets and depending on a button click I want the appropriate DataSet displayed in the grid.

I have tried everything and I cannot get it to show the next DataSet. It sticks with the first one assigned at start up. I am getting to overkill approaches and still nothing is working. Here's where I am at the moment.

```
procedure SetSource(var aSrc : TDataSource);
begin
  aSrc.DataSet.Close;
  dbgridShowData.DataSource:=aSrc;
  aSrc.DataSet.Open;
  aSrc.DataSet.First;
  aSrc.DataSet.Refresh;
end;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are the Datasource bound correct to their datasets? A simple   dbgrid.DataSource := Datasourcexy; should be enough.

Answer (score 6):

You can change the Dataset shown by a DBGrid quite easily at runtime quite easily.  There two approaches:

1: use a single DataSource assigned to DBGrid.DataSource and change the DataSource.DataSet to the desired DataSet.  Here is a simple example with all assignments made at runtime.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;

  DataSet1.Active := true;
  DataSet2.Active := true;
  DataSet3.Active := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataSource1.DataSet := DataSet1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataSource1.DataSet := DataSet2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataSource1.DataSet := DataSet3;
end;
```

2: use a DataSource for each DataSet and change DBGrid.DataSource to the desired DataSource. Here is a simple example with all assignments made at runtime.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataSource1.DataSet := DataSet1;
  DataSource2.DataSet := DataSet2;
  DataSource3.DataSet := DataSet3;

  DataSet1.Active := true;
  DataSet2.Active := true;
  DataSet3.Active := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource2;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource3;
end;
```

If you define the columns of the DBGrid, the structure of the DataSets will need to be the the same, or you will have to change the column definitions when you change the Dataset displayed.

I prefer using a DataSource per DataSet because it is more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to change the `DataSource.DataSet` instead:

```
procedure SetDataFromDataSet(const aDataSource: TDataSource;
  const aNewDataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  aDataSource.DataSet.Close;
  aDataSource.DataSet := aNewDataSet;
  if not aNewDataSet.Active then
    aNewDataSet.Open;
end;
```

Sample use:

```
SetDataFromDataSet(DataSource1, CustomerQuery);
```

You may not want to close and open datasets globally like this, though. It's probably better to do that from the calling code. Of course, that would depend on what you need for your app.

Comment: I think this will 1. cover the underlying problem (suspect datasources are not correct bound) 2. if thinking about a master/detail structure changing then Dataset of a Datasource will be  fatal.

Comment: I don't think your point 2 applies (as that has nothing to do with the question asked). Point 1 may or may not be right; most applications use a single DataSource attached to data-aware controls (such as `TDBGrid`). In that case, you'd leave the one `DataSource` attached to the control and change the `DataSet`; I have a generic viewer for dBASE files (using Advantage Database Server) that allows you to open and browse through any .dbf file, and all it does is assign the `TableName` to a `TAdsTable` and then open the table; the grid automatically creates the necessary columns and displays it.

Comment: Thanks Ken, but that just cleared everything for all selections. Something weird going on here. The global open and close were a last ditch stand. I remmed out my OpenDB and CloseDB functions several hours earlier as the frustration level rose. There are no master/detail issues, these are just flat databases.

Comment: Then you're doing something terribly wrong. Do a new app (File->New->VCL Forms Application). Drop a TDBGrid, TDataSource, and TADOTable on the form. Set the DBGrid1.DataSource to `DataSource1`, the `DataSource1.DataSet` to `ADOQuery1`. Create a connection string to your ADO database of choice, and write a quick `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ` whatever table you have. Set the `ADOQuery1.Active` to `true`. The grid should show data. Add another `ADOQuery`, a connection string, and a `SELECT` on a different table. Change the `DataSource1.DataSet` to `ADOQuery2`, and set the `ADOQuery2.Active` to `True`.

Comment: Now set the `DataSource1.DataSet` back to `ADOQuery1`. Drop a button on the form and double click it. In the code editor: `if (DataSource1.DataSet = ADOQuery1) then DataSource1.DataSet := ADOQuery2 else DataSource1.DataSet := ADOQuery2;`. Run your app, and click the button. The data in the grid should change back and forth between the two `ADOQuery` datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with Delphi5 pro.

```
procedure TForm1.setDataSourceDataSet(var newDataSource:TDataSource);
begin
if DBgrid1.DataSource = nil then begin
   DBgrid1.DataSource:=newDataSource;
end else begin
if DBgrid1.DataSource.Name = newDataSource.Name then exit;
DBGrid1.DataSource.Enabled:=False;
DBgrid1.DataSource:=newDataSource;
end;
If DBgrid1.DataSource.DataSet.active=False then DBgrid1.DataSource.DataSet.active:=True;
DBGrid1.DataSource.Enabled:=True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
setDataSourceDataSet(DataSource1);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
setDataSourceDataSet(DataSource2);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

The secret lies in:

DBGrid1.DataSource.Enabled:=False;
...making changes...
DBGrid1.DataSource.Enabled:=True;

Tested with D5Pro