# Show sqlite database in Delphi XE6 using firedac programmatically

Tags: sqlite, delphi, database-connection, delphi-xe6, firedac

I am new in database using Delphi. Actually I need to display all the tables and their data in a gridview using firedac. Several videos on youtube and docwiki teaches how to access database through visual components i.e. throwing FDConnetion, FDTable, DataSource, etc. on the form.

But I would like to do the same thing programmatically so that I can focus more on coding and separate form from the business logic.

Here is what I have done in C# while accessing MSAccess data:

```
public void LoadUsersInfo()
        {

            try {
                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection();        
                Connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=dbCyberNet.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";        
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = Connection;
                String query = "SELECT * FROM tblUsersInfo";
                command.CommandText = query;

                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                dbGrid.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("Error occured while loading users information . " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally { Connection.Close(); }
        }
```

I would like to do similar in delphi for sqlite database. Here is what I have tried (edited).

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  con: TFDConnection;
  table: TFDTable;
  ds: TDataSource;
begin
  con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  con.LoginPrompt := False;
  table := TFDTable.Create(nil);
  table.TableName := 'Students';
  ds := TDataSource.Create(nil);
  ds.DataSet := table;

  try
    con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=‪studentsDB.sqlite;');
    table.Connection := con;
    table.Active := True;
    con.Connected := True;
    DBGrid1.DataSource := ds;
  finally
    con.Close;
    con.Free;
    table.Free;
    ds.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Whenever I run this code, error dialog appears showing: First chance exception at $759AF097. Exception class ESQLiteNativeException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: no such table: STUDENTS'. Process Project1.exe (3836)

whereas the same table name exists inside the table and using visual firedac components, I can see the data grid fills easily.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try declaring object instances and creating them in code as you did in C#?

Comment: Question edited. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same as with C#: assign your `TFDQuery` instance as DataSource of the VCL grid!

Add a `TDataSource` to the form, set its `DataSet` property to your `TFDQuery`, and assign it to your grid.

See [the official Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Associating_a_Data_Control_with_a_Dataset) and other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397229/458259).

Comment: I have tried something like this. [link](http://pastebin.com/4g5UQYTv) But this doesn;t seem to be a proper way, I guess. btw please excuse my noob skills.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute your `Select` query by calling the query's `Open` method so your code will look like this :-

```
procedure TStudents.executeQuery;
var
  con: TFDConnection;
  query: TFDQuery;
begin
  con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
  con.LoginPrompt := False;
  con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=studentsDB.sqlite;');
  query.Connection := con;
  query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Students';
  query.Open;
  query.First;
  While Not Query.EOF Do
  Begin
    // Populate your object or do whatever processing you like here.
    Query.Next;
  End;
end;
```

You can then programatically create a `TDataSource` and a Grid and hook those up in code in a similar fashion. You'll need to move the Connection and Query objects out of your object's `executeQuery` method as they are local variables and will not be accessible to anything outside that method.

Note that Delphi does not garbage collect like C# does, so as it stand, the code leaks memory.

As an aside, your code appears to be an object method and it looks like you're attempting to create a set of business objects that know how to load and save themselves. Rather than roll your own, you might be better served by looking at one of the existing frameworks that exist (tiOPF, InstantObjects, mORMot or TMS Aurelius) to achieve this. These will allow you to concentrate on solving the problem at hand and not worry about the minutae of creating, loading and saving of objects.

Comment: Your sample code is leaking memory! con and query variables are not freed. This is far from good reference code to show... :( BTW, the OP does not at all specify about object persistence, but only fill a visual grid.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez You're right the code does leak memory, but I took the OP's original code and just appended the necessary steps rather than re-write the whole thing for him. I've updated my answer to include a comment on leaking memory.

Comment: @Andy_D: As I can see, it works using your code but it seems memory leak issues. Pardon my child skills in Delphi but I cannot free those connection and query objects using try..finally block. It shows invlaid pointer operation error dialog. Btw I have updated my code, please have a look.

Comment: @RabiJayasawal Don't make your connection and queries local variables. Delphi has the concept of Datamodules which provide a central point for your data access components. See the documentation for more information http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Data_Modules

Comment: Yes data modules are the rad way to do it. I really hate it personally but it is how rad works.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez it's either that or some kind of OPF (incidentally, I updated my answer to include mORMot as I left it off the list. My apologies, Arnaud!